# .innerHTML on array text?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I just want to make an array string be read as HTML and not literally show the html code when showed.

What I want to see: **español**
What I actually see: `<b>espa&ntilde;ol</b>`

Tried using innerHTML but didn't work.

```
aLangKeys['es']['language']=('<b>espa&ntilde;ol</b>').innerHTML;
```

```js
var aLangKeys=new Array();
aLangKeys['en']=new Array();
aLangKeys['es']=new Array();
aLangKeys['fr']=new Array();
aLangKeys['cn']=new Array();

aLangKeys['en']['language']='english';
aLangKeys['es']['language']='<b>espa&ntilde;ol</b>';
aLangKeys['fr']['language']='français';
aLangKeys['cn']['language']='中文';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **What I actually see: < b > espa&ntilde;ol </ b >

Comment: why not `aLangKeys['es']['language']='español'` ?

Comment: The problem is *showing* the text, not creating it. Show that part of the code.

Comment: You are right JJJ

Comment: $('.translate').each(function(i){
          $(this).text(aLangKeys[lang][ $(this).attr('key') ]);
        }

Comment: Well, yes, `.text()` inserts the string as text. If you want to insert HTML, use `.html()`.

Comment: Have you tried innerText instead?